# Inkscape stroke hardly visible when it's too thin

Tags: inkscape, stroke

I have the last version of inkscape but I have a problem. With my laser cutter I need strokes with a thickness of 0,01. But whenever I change the thickness of a shape or line to this value, the stroke is so thin that I can't see it unless I zoom in really close. With an old version of Inkscape I didn't have the problem. I'm sure there is something to do in the parameters but I don't know how to do this and I don't find anything on internet. 
Does someone have a solution please? 
Many thanks

Comment: Use the outline display mode.  View > Display Mode > Outline

Comment: This feature is new to me. I suggest that it is better suited as an answer, especially as it was valuable to me and would upvote it.

Comment: @fred_dot_u done!

Answer (score 6):

If you set the display mode to outline by clicking *View > Display Mode > Outline*, you will be able to see the outline no matter what zoom level you have set.  Outline mode shows all paths as simple outlines, whether they have a stroke/fill applied or not.

This could be useful in many kinds of situations where you just want to see the paths without the confusion of strokes/fills.

You can toggle the display modes in Inkscape using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> - that's 5 on the number pad.

Comment: Thank you it worked it will help but do you think there is somewhere in the display parameters where you can choose to see the strokes even if they are really thin ? Like in the old versions of Inkscape.

Comment: @Louissia Not as far as I know.

Comment: Additionally, you will be happy to hear that another display mode is coming in the next version. It's called 'visible hairlines'. See http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/1.0#Visible_Hairlines_Display_Mode .